# seq2seq prediction for time series

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

I want to make a Seq2Seq model for reconstruction purpose. I want a model trained to reconstruct the normal time-series and it is assumed that such a model would do badly to reconstruct the anomalous time-series having not seen them during training.

I have some gaps in my code and also in the understanding. I took this as an orientation and did so far: 
traindata: input_data.shape(1000,60,1) and target_data.shape(1000,50,1) with target data being the same training data only in reversed order as sugested in the paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.06154.pdf).
for inference: I want to predict another time series data with the trained model having the shape (3000,60,1). T Now 2 points are open: how do I specify the input data for my training model and how do I build the inference part with the stop condition ?  
Please correct any mistakes.

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense

num_encoder_tokens = 1#number of features
num_decoder_tokens = 1#number of features
encoder_seq_length = None
decoder_seq_length = None
batch_size = 50
epochs = 40

# same data for training 
input_seqs=()#shape (1000,60,1) with sliding windows
target_seqs=()#shape(1000,60,1) with sliding windows but reversed
x= #what has x to be ?

#data for inference 
# how do I specify the input data for my other time series ?

# Define training model
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(encoder_seq_length,
                          num_encoder_tokens))
encoder = LSTM(128, return_state=True, return_sequences=True)
encoder_outputs = encoder(encoder_inputs)
_, encoder_states = encoder_outputs[0], encoder_outputs[1:]

decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(decoder_seq_length,
                          num_decoder_tokens))
decoder = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)
decoder_outputs = decoder(decoder_inputs, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_outputs = TimeDistributed(
Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation='tanh'))(decoder_outputs)
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)

# Training
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit([input_seqs,x], target_seqs,
      batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)


# Define sampling models for inference
encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)

decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape=(100,))
decoder_state_input_c = Input(shape=(100,))
decoder_states = [decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]
decoder_outputs = decoder(decoder_inputs,
                      initial_state=decoder_states)
decoder_model = Model([decoder_inputs] + decoder_states,
decoder_outputs)

# Sampling loop for a batch of sequences
states_values = encoder_model.predict(input_seqs)
stop_condition = False
while not stop_condition:
    output_tokens = decoder_model.predict([target_seqs] + states_values)
#what else do I need to include here ? 
    break
```

Comment: I have a similar problem of sequence to sequence prediction. I have a total of 9000 samples with the shape (9000, 200, 1). After dividing into train and test set e,g of shapes (6000,200,1) and (3000, 200, 1). 

Did you do any thing extra in while loop, and how you called predict_sequence in your code?

Comment: @annulstudent93 I have a similar question posted on stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58491120/how-to-model-the-data-for-sequence-to-sequence-prediction-with-only-one-feature

but I didn't get any answer. Can you please help me how and where you called predict_sequence function in your code. And what else did you do in the while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def predict_sequence(infenc, infdec, source, n_steps, cardinality):
    # encode
    state = infenc.predict(source)
    # start of sequence input
    target_seq = array([0.0 for _ in range(cardinality)]).reshape(1, 1, cardinality)
    # collect predictions
    output = list()
    for t in range(n_steps):
        # predict next char
        yhat, h, c = infdec.predict([target_seq] + state)
        # store prediction
        output.append(yhat[0,0,:])
        # update state
        state = [h, c]
        # update target sequence
        target_seq = yhat
    return array(output)
```

You can see that the output from every timestep is fed back to the LSTM cell externally.

Comment: when I use this, the model waits for the same sequence length so regarding my example above I need the data with (1000,60,1) and can not use data with shape (2000,60,1) for inference, why is this happening ?

Comment: at what point predict_sequence will be called and how? @pranoy

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the blog and find how it is done during inference.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-encoder-decoder-model-sequence-sequence-prediction-keras/

Answer (score 0):

During training, we give the data in a one shot manner. I think you understand that part.

But during the inference time, we can't do like that. We have to give the data at every time step and then return the cell states, hidden states and the loop should continue till the last word is generated